# I got an error while creating sub menu in my database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to laravel. I want to create submenu for my website using the eloquent. However it gives me and error saying that

*Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shopping.sub_menus' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `sub_menus` where `sub_menus`.`menu_id` = 1 and `sub_menus`.`menu_id` is not null)*

my model menu
**Menu.php**

```
class Menu extends Model
{


   public function submenu()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(SubMenu::class);
   }
}

 // SubMenu Model
class SubMenu extends Model
{
   public function menu()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Menu::class);
   }
}
```

and below is blade
**side-nav.blade.php**

```
 <ul>
    @foreach ($menu as $_menu)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ route($_menu->route) }}" id={{ $_menu->id }} class="side-menu">
            @if ($_menu->submene->count())
            <ul>
                @foreach ($_menu->submenu as $_submenu)
                <li><a href="{{ route($_menu->route) }}" id={{ $_menu->id }}>{{$_submenu->$_menu}} </a></li>@endforeach
            <div class="side-menu__icon"> <i data-feather={{ $_menu->icon_name }}></i> </div>
            <div class="side-menu__title"> {{ $_menu->menu_name }} </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Silly question: have you actually created that table? Have you run migrations?

Comment: yes i did the migration

Comment: I believe you can define table name in your model to resolve such issue `protected $table = 'sub_menu';`